# Executable created in CentOS not working in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, centos, pyinstaller, ubuntu-11.04

I have developed a pygtk application. Now I have to deploy it on a client machine.

So I created an executable using PyInstaller in a CentOS 5 machine (since Pyinstaller depends on glibc and to select lower glibc I used centOS 5).

Now when I'm trying to run the application in Ubuntu11.04 Machine it loads the application but instead of text it shows the square boxes in GUI.

And following error messages get printed in the command line.

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:88: GtkWarning: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/home/arrowdevices/pda/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:94: GtkWarning: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/home/arrowdevices/pda/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:100: GtkWarning: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/home/arrowdevices/pda/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:114: GtkWarning: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/home/arrowdevices/pda/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:120: GtkWarning: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/home/arrowdevices/pda/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:130: GtkWarning: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/home/arrowdevices/pda/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:140: GtkWarning: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/home/arrowdevices/pda/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:197: PangoWarning: No modules found:
No builtin or dynamically loaded modules were found.
PangoFc will not work correctly.
This probably means there was an error in the creation of:
  '/home/arrowdevices/pda/etc/pango/pango.modules'
You should create this file by running:
  pango-querymodules > '/home/arrowdevices/pda/etc/pango/pango.modules'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcd-filter-lcddefault.conf", line 9: invalid constant used : lcddefault
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/53-monospace-lcd-filter.conf", line 17: invalid constant used : lcdlegacy
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:197: PangoWarning: failed to find shape engine, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='latin'
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:197: PangoWarning: failed to find shape engine, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='common'
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:197: GtkWarning: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/home/arrowdevices/pda/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
```

My questions:

1. How can I cleanly package the icons and fonts into the executable created by PyInstaller?
2. Pyinstaller seems to be hardcoding file paths into the executable. How can we avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd search for Ubuntu binary. CentOS and Ubuntu are **very, very** different system. The catalog structure can vary.

Comment: Hi @over-killer I changed the questions, pls have a look. I need to cleanly package the icons and fonts using pyinstaller. I think then there should be no difference between Ubuntu and CentOS

Comment: Okay. Install development GTK+ files. Install also PangoFC. To make it working I wonder.
Why do You think that between Ubuntu and CentOS are no differences?
Ubuntu is based upon Debian and CentOS is based upon RHEL. They use different packages managers and catalog structure is different.

Comment: Hey I installed same centos 5 on another machine and tested my application, but its giving the same error. Any Idea why?

Comment: Did You installed all dev libs with I mentioned above?

Comment: hey i have compiled all the sources(required for gtk, pygtk includinf pango and cairo) to a local directory and ran pyinstaller. I did not find any package for pangoFC separately, how can I install that?

Comment: Here: [link](http://www.pango.org). Download sources (or package) and install it.

Comment: As I said in previous comment I have installed pango and cairo, still I'm getting the error. Is pangoFC a different package? the link you have sent doesn't have sources/packages in it.

Comment: Ah sorry. I thought that pangoFC belongs to pango package. I don't know now how to help you. Sorry :(

Comment: Hey now I know how to get the application run on client machine. I copied pango.modules and loader.cache files in the client place(I manually created the path /home/arrowdevices/pda and copied the files) and its working fine now. You have any idea how can I configure pango ModulesPath so that I can place the pango.modules anywhere on the system?